# Use of include in fractal transformer Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I used this library for adding fractal transformer to my json output.

```js
//This is main tranformer for service provider enquiry transformer

  class CustomerVehicleTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {

          protected $defaultIncludes = [
            'service_provider_enquries'
        ];
        public function transform(CustomerVehicle $customerVehicle) {
           
                return [
                     'id'      => (int) $customerVehicle->id,
                    'status'   =>$customerVehicle->vehiclenumber
                    ];
            }

       public function includeServiceProviderEnquries(CustomerVehicle $customerVehicle) {

            $serviceProvider = $customerVehicle->service_provider_enquries;
            return $this->item($serviceProvider, new ServiceProvidersEnquiryTransformer);
        }
    }
```

```js
class ServiceProvidersEnquiryTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {


    public function transform(ServiceProvidersEnquiry $book) {
        return [
            'modeofpayment'      => (int) $book->modeofpayment
        ];
    }


}
```

calling from controller

```js
       $manager =new Fractal\Manager();
        if (isset($_GET['include'])) {
            $manager->parseIncludes($_GET['include']);
        }
        $json = $manager->createData($resource)->toJson();
         echo $json;
```

When I try to run this code it throws the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Acme\FractalTransformers\ServiceProvidersEnquiryTransformer::transform()
>   must be an instance of App\ServiceProvidersEnquiry, null given, called
>   in /home/aidor/Documents/ozoServer/vendor/league/fractal/src/Scope.php
>   on line 307 and defined

What could be the problem? Suggest, please, some example of defaultincludes and availableIncludes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that `$resource` is null, you need to pass it an instance of `ServiceProvidersEnquiry` you're also missing some key lines of code to set up the response. Double check the documentation to check you're doing everything right and understand WHY it's not working: http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/

You should be doing something like this I think:

```
// set up data
$enquiry = App\ServiceProvidersEnquiry::first();

// set up fractal manager
$manager = new Fractal\Manager();

if (isset($_GET['include'])) {
    $manager->parseIncludes($_GET['include']);
}

$fractal->setSerializer(new Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer());

// set up response item
$response = new Fractal\Resource\Item($enquiry, new \PathToYourTransformer\ServiceProvidersEnquiryTransformer);

return response()->json($fractal->createData($response)->toArray());
```